# How do I size a cylinder for a soda to fit specific image dimensions for uv wrapping?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

I’m making a 3d model for a seltzer brand, who has given me the artwork they want on the can. the can is supposedly 330 ml, but I’ve tried making the two different types of ‘real world’ 330 ml cans, and when I unwrap the uv the aspect ratio is wrong on both cans.

How would I go about reverse engineering a soda can which would be able to fit the aspect ratio of the artwork that I have?

The size of the image is 1962px x 1336px for reference. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Start by changing your base units to something smaller (like centimeters), and add a plane:

[image: Can1]

Bring up the transform menu with N and change the dimensions of the plane to that of your image. Make sure to apply scale afterwards (Ctrl + A > Scale):

[image: Can2]

Enter edit mode and rotate your object so it's "upright" (90 degrees on the x for me). Add a bunch of loop cuts to facilitate the bending (I did 24):

[image: Can3]

Add a Simple Deform Modifier, set to *Bend* and pick the Z axis (this is because we rotated a flat plane upright earlier without applying rotation - it's ok). Change the bend degrees to 360.

[image: Can4]

That makes the can shape that will fit the label - the tops and bottoms (above and below) will be all "metal" I assume. You can unwrap the can piece and extrude those parts later (whether or not you unwrap them is up to you - just unwrap them separately to the "main piece").  For the can, make sure to do a straight unwrap (U > unwrap - choose a straight on ortho perspective before doing so (Numpad 1 or 3)) BEFORE applying the modifier (while it's still a plane). You may need to rotate the UV map afterwards by 90 deg (and maybe scale it slightly). That should make it fit your texture.

If there's a "gap" after you apply the modifier and add a subdivision surface (don't worry - you'll see it). Just select the whole mesh in edit mode and press M (merge) and select "by distance"